# Unexpected Conversion Error String to BigNumber - Pentaho DI

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

In using the `CSV Input` step on a very large file, I'm getting the following error:

> 2018/09/03 14:16:43 - Select values.0 - Unexpected conversion error while converting value [ID String(255)] to a BigNumber
>
> 2018/09/03 14:16:43 - Select values.0 - ID String(255) : couldn't convert string value 'L 160-168' to a big number.

I've already tried using regex for eliminating line breaks and whitespace.

Comment: How big is your file ?

Comment: Which step? `CSV Input` or `Text file input` ?

Comment: It's a csv file 1.25GB and I originally used CSV Input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'L 160-168' is not a number.

If it is not an error in your data (which should then be corrected by your data provider), nor an bug in your data definition, you may read the data as a String, and then change its type.

To change the type, you can use the step `Select values` (tab `Metadata`) on which you have an error handling. Alternatively, if you need to make some processing on the data, you can convert it with a `Javascript value` step.

If the error is in the data, it may be due to a misplaced line break or some field missing. To put your finger on the error : cut the file in two at one line before the non numeric ID. The second file should break on the first line, and the first file should read OK although the error will be on the last line.

When you know where the error is, the problem is half solved.

Comment: Hi, so, I've searched 'L 160-168' in the original file and it only appears at a different column named "Complemento". ID is the first column and is originally only filled with numeric values.

Do you think it's possible that some line break or something like that made the CSV File Input in Pentaho read it as information from a different column?

Comment: Yes, probably. Though Pentaho is RC4180 compatible, meaning the error comes from the data producer will not be easy to find. Edited my answer to propose a solution.